# FlatList pull up from bottom of list

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm using the FlatList component of React-Native, which be default refreshes when pulled down at the top of the list.

```
<FlatList
    data={reviews}
    keyExtractor={item=> item.review_id}
    renderItem={({item}) => (
      <ReviewItem
        review = {item}
      />
    )}
    refreshing = {true}
    onRefresh = {refreshReviews}
    ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <ListSeperator />}
  />
```

The way I want to show reviews is the latest appears on top of the list and when I reach the bottom of the list and I pull up then it should load the next batch of reviews.

How can I do this? Will the behaviour be the same in iOS and Android ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this:

```
onEndReached={this.loadPosts.bind(this)}
onEndReachedThreshold={0}
ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter(this.props.loading)}
```

are useful to load the next contents when the list reaches the end.

*ListFooterComponent* is here to show an activity indicator to tell the user that something is loading

If you want to show new content when the user gets to the bottom and then pull to refresh, imho is not very clear for the user as UX.
Is more obvious load new contents scrolling to bottom

Comment: yea I see your point, loading content automatically without needing to pull gives better experience. But the same could be said for pull to refresh at the top of the list.

Comment: @user3434013 pull to refresh was created to load new content, not to load old content... For example, if the first post I see is dated November 10, when I pull to refresh I expect to see new posts dated November 11 and so on. When I come to the bottom I expect to find ever older posts dated November 9th and so on